# AJAX Interval Refresh?

Tags: jquery, ajax, intervals

I'm trying to make an AJAX function update about 30 seconds. I have a simple version of that done, here is the code.

```
var refInterval = window.setInterval('update()', 30000); // 30 seconds

var update = function() {
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'post.php',
        success : function(data){
            $('.voters').html(data);
        },
    });
};
```

This works, however, when the function is FIRST called I don't want it to wait 30 seconds, I just want the function to call, then wait 30 seconds, call again, wait 30 seconds, call again, etc. Any help?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Consider using `setTimeout` instead - it's more reliable.  `setInterval` timers can stack when the window doesn't have focus and then all run at once when it gets focus back again.  Using `setTimeout` also ensures that you don't get multiple AJAX requests queued up if the first one blocks for some reason.

To start the loop immediately, use an IIFE ("immediately invoked function expression") wrapped around the function:

```
(function update() {
    $.ajax({
        ...                        // pass existing options
    }).then(function() {           // on completion, restart
       setTimeout(update, 30000);  // function refers to itself
    });
})();                              // automatically invoke for first run
```

p.s. don't use string arguments to `setInterval` or `setTimeout` - just pass the function reference directly.

Comment: +1 The only person to explain passing the function as an object, rather than a string, *and* for using `setTimeout` after the function completes, so the function never tries to run whilst it's already running (unlikely, I know, but I always safeguard in the same way).

Comment: Thanks mate.  your code helps me to achieve my result.    I achieved in bit different way.                                                                                      function refresh(refreshSeconds) {
                timer = setInterval(function () {                  

                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")',
                        type: 'POST',
                        success: function (result) {
                        },
                    });
                }, (refreshSeconds * 1000));
            }

Comment: @siva that use of `setInterval` is a bad idea, for the reasons outlined above

Comment: @Alnitak  I replaced it now with setInterval.  Works perfect.. Great!

Answer (score 2):

Just call update right after you define it:

```
var refInterval = window.setInterval('update()', 30000); // 30 seconds

var update = function() {
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'post.php',
        success : function(data){
            $('.voters').html(data);
        },
    });
};
update();
```

Answer (score 1):

Call update once (on document ready) before calling it with the interval:

```
update();

var refInterval = window.setInterval('update()', 30000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Invoke the function before setting the timer.

Like so:

```
 var update = function() {
     $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'post.php',
        success : function(data){
            $('.voters').html(data);
        },
    });
};
update();
var refInterval = window.setInterval('update()', 30000); // 30 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

just put the setTimeout into your successhandler and it should work like charm

```
var update = function() {
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'post.php',
        success : function(data){
            $('.voters').html(data);
            var refInterval = window.setTimeout('update()', 30000); // 30 seconds
        },
    });
};

update()
```