# Polymer iron-ajax interval calls

Tags: javascript, ajax, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a simple Polymer frontend app. In it, I have simple ajax to get data from the backend:

```
<iron-ajax id="getAjax"
  auto
  url="http://localhost:14039/InvoiceService/envelop/{{envelopId}}/invoices"
  handle-as="json"
  last-response="{{invoices}}">
```

The ajax gets called at startup and works. Whenever I POST using other iron-ajaxes I call `this.$.getAjax.generateRequest();` and it works.

Question is, how can I call this function using some sort of timer. The idea here is to "refresh" the page using iron-ajax.
I saw some answers on [how to do it on JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24494805/ajax-interval-refresh), but I get confused with Polymers properties vs functions vs internal functions vs this.$ etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You would use Polymer's `async()` method, as described in the [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/instance-methods#async-and-debounce):

> - [`async(method, [wait])`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/Polymer.Base#method-async). Calls `method` asynchronously. If no wait time is specified, runs tasks with microtask timing (after the current method finishes, but before the next event from the event queue is processed). Returns a handle that can be used to cancel the task.
> - [`cancelAsync(handle)`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/Polymer.Base#method-cancelAsync). Cancels the identified async task.

The following example defines `_updateData()` that asynchronously re-sends the AJAX request after 2 seconds. This could be called inside an `on-response` handler of `<iron-ajax>` so that the request is resent 2 seconds after every response.

```
Polymer({
  is: 'x-foo',
  _updateData: function() {
    this.async(function() {
      this.$.ajax.generateRequest();
    }, 2000);
  },
  _onResponse: function() {
    this._updateData();
  }
});
```

Here's a working demo:

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.11.1/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <iron-ajax id="ajax"
                 auto
                 url="//jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/"
                 last-response="{{data}}"
                 on-response="_onResponse"
                 handleAs="json">
      </iron-ajax>
      <table>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[data]]">
          <tr>
            <td>[[item.id]]</td>
            <td>[[item.name]]</td>
            <td>[[item.email]]</td>
          </tr>
        </template>
      </table>
      <div>
        <sup>See console log</sup>
      </div>
    </template>
    <script>
      HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
        Polymer({
          is: 'x-foo',
          _updateData: function() {
            this.async(function() {
              this.$.ajax.generateRequest();
            }, 2000);
          },
          _onResponse: function() {
            console.log('received response');
            this._updateData();
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

<sup>[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/sabukomage/edit?html,console,output)</sup>

Comment: I added the _updateData function to Polymer json (I replaced this.$.ajax with this.$.getAjax, which is the id of my iron-ajax element. Called it on the ready function with this._updateData() and using chrome, I can see the call firing twice, once on ready, and another after two seconds. Same thing on your sample. Is it required to call async again on the on-response handler? (which i'm not using, as I use last-response, but can be added)

Comment: Yes, I intentionally made only two calls so that you could see how to use `async`. It could be easily modified to be made continuous by moving _updateData from ready() into _onResponse(). I had added the on-response handler in my example to demonstrate that a second response was received.

Comment: I accepted your answer. I would like you to add that last part to the answer for future references. Thank you!