# Jquery SetInterval not refreshing data coming from a API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an API that generates two random numbers, I would like `Jquery` and `AJAX` to get new numbers every second. The data is not refreshing. There are no console errors.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            setInterval(function() {
                $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};
                $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT+"/API",
                    function(data) {
                        $("#rand1").text(data.rand1)
                        $("#rand2").text(data.rand2)
                    });
            },
        1000);
        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="rand1"></div>
    <div id="rand2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Only output I see (numbers are just an example):

```
{
  "rand1": 0.8547685117870685, 
  "rand2": 0.8581594988448931
}
```

EDIT: This question was marked as a possible duplicate. The other question provides a solution that may work, but implementing a different approach. I would like to keep my basic code and get help figuring out why it doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AJAX Interval Refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24494805/ajax-interval-refresh)

Comment: This is probably a caching issue. Try adding a timestamp to the URL, or specify `cache: false` in `$.ajaxSetup()`. That being said, do not use AJAX polling. It's an anti-pattern that only results in you DDOS-ing your own server. If you need to keep the server and client data in sync, look in to using WebSockets or Server Sent Events instead.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I think my server can handle the requests. They will only be coming from me on one connection. I tried putting in `cache: false` with no change.