# How to file_get_contents & refresh data without page reload using php ajax

Tags: php, ajax, api, file-get-contents, reload

I am taking some json data from an API using php. I'd like the data to refresh every 20 seconds without having to manually reload the page. This is my code below that works great at fetching the data. Just need to figure out how to refresh - maybe with ajax?

```
$getdata = file_get_contents("https://data.website.com/");
$datajson = json_decode($getdata);
$mydata = $datajson->whatiwant;
echo $mydata;
```

Comment: Not 100% sure what you're getting at, but perhaps you really want a cron?

Comment: The data is always changing so I'd like to refresh the file_get_contents data every 20 seconds

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AJAX Interval Refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24494805/ajax-interval-refresh)

Answer (score 0):

request your data using AJAX:

```
function requestMyData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/url/to/interface.php",
        type: get,
        success: function(data) {
            //update your UI here
        }
    });
}
```

you are then able to request the data using a timeout:

```
setTimeout(requestMyData(), 100);
```