# How to redirect on Flask after Redis background task is done?

Tags: python, flask, redis

I'm using Redis Queue to process a background task on a Flask app. When I press a button on the HTMLtemplate, the `update()` function make the `task()` function work in the background. After clicking button, I pass the variable  `message`, which shows a message on the HTML, letting know the user that the task is being done. But when the task is done,I want to let the user know it. How can I redirect to another page, or change the `message` content at least?

I've seen this answer: [How do I return flask render_template after the Redis background job is done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59490025/how-do-i-return-flask-render-template-after-the-redis-background-job-is-done)
But I do not want the page to update every certain amount of time. I want a single update when background task is done.

Example code:

```js
app = Flask(__name__)

q = Queue(connection=conn)


def task():

    print("Starting background task")
    time.sleep(10)
    return "Background task finished"
    # Redirect no another page

@ app.route("/update")
def update():

    job = q.enqueue(task)
    message = "Doing the task..."
    return redirect(url_for("index.html", message=message))
```

Comment: Hey, I'm the author of that post you linked.  Check it again: I've now made an edit which uses Server Sent Events to display a progress bar on the frontend (without refreshing the page).  This may be of some use to you :-)

Comment: @v25 I uploaded your code to Heroku, works fine. I took a while to fully understand it. Would you consider this approach better than using websockets for this kind of tasks? Why

Comment: imo (and just my opinion) the SSE method integrates quite nicely with a larger app which doesn't use websockets, because it's just a single endpoint to stream the progress, and some minimal JS code on the client side.   I guess it depends what your exisiting code looks like.  If you're starting a new app you may wish to go with websockets, but that's a design choice which is up to you.