# FastAPI handle request time out

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn

I have an API endpoint in which I am trying to processing the csv file and passing it to the scraper function after scraping is done I am downloading the scraped result as a csv file generated by scraper function, all functioning as I expected but when I deploy it on heroku after uploading the csv file after few seconds it occurs 503 response which means request timed out. So, I want to ask how can I handle the request time out error properly in a sense it won't crash and run till the scraper is running and file has been downloaded.

```
import fastapi as _fastapi
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse, FileResponse
import shutil
import os

from scraper import run_scraper


app = _fastapi.FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
def index():
    content = """
<body>
<form method="post" action="/api/v1/scraped_csv" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="csv_file" type="file" multiple>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
    """
    return HTMLResponse(content=content)


@app.post("/api/v1/scraped_csv")
async def extract_ads(csv_file: _fastapi.UploadFile = _fastapi.File(...)):
    temp_file = _save_file_to_disk(csv_file, path="temp", save_as="temp")
    await run_scraper(temp_file)
    csv_path = os.path.abspath(clean_file)
    return FileResponse(path=csv_path, media_type="text/csv", filename=clean_file)


def _save_file_to_disk(uploaded_file, path=".", save_as="default"):
    extension = os.path.splitext(uploaded_file.filename)[-1]
    temp_file = os.path.join(path, save_as + extension)
    with open(temp_file, "wb") as buffer:
        shutil.copyfileobj(uploaded_file.file, buffer)
    return temp_file
```

Here is the link for the app.

https://fast-api-google-ads-scraper.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Is your run scraper [awaitable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#awaitables) object?

Comment: Yes, using asyncio.

Comment: Is it a long running job? If it is, are you queueing this as a background job?

Comment: Yeah it is a long running job, but can't use background task because if I use background task scraped results won't get downloaded it will download a empty file.

Comment: I would recommend asynchronous API for this purpose. Create an endpoint which will just start the scraping, and the process will be further taken care by fastapi background tasks or some asynchronous task library like celery, dramatiq etc.

Answer (score 1):

I currently see two possibilities.

1st, you increase the waiting time before the timeout.
If you use Gunicorn you can use `-t INT` or `--timeout INT` knowing that Value is a positive number or 0. Setting it to 0 has the effect of infinite timeouts by disabling timeouts for all workers entirely.

Second one, you use an asynchronous request/response. You respond immediately with a 202 and tell the client where he can track the status of the task but this requires creating a new endpoint, new logic, etc...

Comment: I have tried `--timeout-keep-alive=0` but still crashing with 503. I am using uvicorn.

Comment: Same here. I get 503 error. I want to load a big model in the beginning. Not working with fastapi

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be what @fchancel is suggesting. Run scraping as a background task via a Redis Queue and inform the user that a job with `job_id` (key in redis) has been created. The worker dynos can store the results of the background job in a blob storage. You can fetch your results from the blob storage using `job_id`.

For knowing the status of the job, kindly have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59490025/how-do-i-return-flask-render-template-after-the-redis-background-job-is-done)