# Refresh Script Without Reloading the whole page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

hello guys i have a Div script that change each 30 mn for example
can i refresh this Div Script from the data server without reloading the whole page (client side)
this is the html script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var today = new Date();
<script >
```

Div Xpath is

```
/html/head/script[9]/text()
```

Comment: I don't understand what your question/issue is

Comment: Yes you can, and you know you can as you have tagged AJAX. I assume what you actually want is someone to write it for you, but you dont even provde enough information for someone to so that

Comment: @RiggsFolly How do i Provide enough info im kinda noob sorry For that

Comment: You already accepted an answer so I guess you are all sorted!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

See this answer: [AJAX Interval Refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24494805/ajax-interval-refresh)

When you use the interval to retrieve data every x seconds, then you can select the DIV and insert the new data there.

```
(function update() {
    $.ajax({
        //Retrieve the new data here
    }).then(function() {           // on completion, restart after 30 seconds
        //Insert new data here
        //Example: $('.classname').html(data);
       setTimeout(update, 30000);  // function refers to itself
    });
    })();
```

Comment: Hey bro im kinda Noob What should i put in the retrive the new data 
and in the insert new data ? 
the example i get it i guess

Comment: [Here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) you can find more information about how to do a GET request with AJAX.